# Dynamically hide all sub folder but initial

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Essentially, I need to edit the `.htaccess` file to develop a way to hide folder structure after `/file`. For example, if I have this URL:

```
https://www.example.com/file/page/work/assignments.php?
```

**I should only see**  `https://www.example.com/file/assignments.php?`

How can this be accomplished?

So far I have tried the following, but it does hide all folders after first:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains on the same account? What URL are you linking to internally? The `page/work` part is presumably a fixed file-path?

Comment: Please see my comment, I am looking for a more dynamic approach, where the I would need to dynamically hide the folder structure beyond the initial “file”

Comment: But how would the system know where to fetch the file from?

Comment: @MrWhite Is it instead possible to hide all sub folders dynamically except for the last? So display only display work/assignment.php and hide the rest?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following to "hide" `page/work` after the `/file/` directory and before the last path segment.

This needs to go in the root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/folder/page/work/<file>" to "/folder/<file>"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(folder)/page/work/([^/]+)$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]

# Rewrite "/folder/<file>" back to "/folder/page/work/<file>" (if it exists)
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/page/work/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^(folder)/([^/]+)$ $1/page/work/$2 [L]
```

The will externally redirect a request for `/folder/page/work/assignments.php?something` to `/folder/assignments.php?something`. And internally rewrite the request back again.

NB: You should already be linking to `/folder/<file>` internally. The initial redirect to remove `page/work` is just for SEO if you are changing an existing URL structure. Otherwise, this is not strictly necessary.

---

A look at your existing rule...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
> RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
> ```

This would seem to be unrelated to what you are trying to achieve. It would internally rewrite a request for `/<anything>` to `/subfolder/<anything>`, essentially "hiding" `/subfolder`.

There is no need to check the requested `Host` header unless you are accepting requests to multiple domains and this is specific to just one of those domains. (You've made no mention of this in your question.)

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically take and hide all directories ahead of the first (file) and always hide it? That way there is no need to hard code the path? The reason I ask is because I need this to apply across the web app.

Comment: @StephanieSmith I thought you might have been hoping for a more dynamic solution, but that's impossible with the scenario as stated. How do you know what URL-path the request should be written to? eg. How do you know that a request for `/file/application.php` should be rewritten to `/file/page/work/application.php` and not `/file/foo/application.php?` If there are limited number of locations then each one can be tested, although that becomes inefficient very quickly.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the opposite? Meaning instead only displaying the last sub folder “work” from the original example and hiding everything before it?

Comment: @StephanieSmith Only if the `/file/page/` prefix is fixed (or there is a limited number of directories to "test"), otherwise you have exactly the same problem.

Comment: Understood. In that case, if a url contains “file/page/“ I am looking to hide it. How can this be done? I appreciate your help.